# Find unique ZIP codes and add to field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, concatenation

I have multiple values in a table with the same CODE(Name) and each one has a ZIP. How to find all of the unique ZIP codes and add them to a field.

Here is an example of the result I am looking for:

```
NAME   ZIP        RESULT  
A      17112      17112,15345,17102  
A      15345      17112,15345,17103  
A      17102      17112,15345,17104  
B      17504      17504,17112  
B      17112      17504,17112
```

Comment: In your results for `A` the last value changes - `17102` to `17103` to `17104` - is this the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a comma delimited text file of your data.
- Open it in ArcMAp, save it to a Table
- Add a new field to the Table, I named it Zips
- Download and run this Concatenate Row Value Tool.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=52dfcef46fdb4c76bfbc08dc01570f3c

- Run Summary Statistics, choose First, Zips; then Name for the Case
  field.

[image]

[image]

[image]